# Facebook - Get All Messages from Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Response from request for getting messages about specific conversation are returning just IDs from the all separate messages that are contained in that conversation. So, if I want to get all of the messages from all conversation, there will be a lot of request...

Are there any solution for getting all of the messages(text from messages) from specific conversation in one request? Or any other workaround for this kind of issue?

Here is the example:

Request: `XXX?fields=subject,message_count,messages` -> (where XXX are id of conversation)
Response:

```
{
  "message_count": 4,
  "id": "XXX",
  "messages": {
    "data": [
      {
        "created_time": "2016-05-11T08:29:56+0000",
        "id": "id1"
      },
      {
        "created_time": "2016-05-11T08:29:54+0000",
        "id": "id2"
      },
      {
        "created_time": "2016-05-11T08:21:56+0000",
        "id": "id3"
      },
      {
        "created_time": "2016-05-09T14:04:17+0000",
        "id": "id4"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using the [conversation details endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/conversation/messages); have you tried using the [`/messages/`edge](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/conversation/messages) of the same endpoint?

Try to rewrite your request as:

`XXX/messages?fields=message,subject,to`